# How could I change the position of a button after transition?

Tags: android

I want to change the position of my button after transition ... but I have used animation xml for transition ! but the button comes to its position again ! how could I change the position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation_name);
anim.setFillAfter(true); 
anim.setDuration(1000);
```

Mark as right, if it works for you.

Comment: thank you very much :) ....... ya it is right but but the button is comming back to its previous position  ... how to make it stuck at its last postion ? thank you in advace !